# What does _serial_.bufferUntil(byte) do, and how does it synergies with serialEvent?

Tags: bluetooth, byte, processing

I am having trouble understanding this. Upon searching I found

> Sets a specific byte to buffer until before calling serialEvent()

This is from [this link](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html) from the Processing Website

Serial event is the function, that the user states by putting in the Serial port defined as the function, if I’m not mistaken.

But I have seen `bufferUntil(‘\n’)` when nothing’s being sent to the Serial, so what is this doing, and what does it mean before calling serialEvent() this is put in setup how could it be called each time before a function? And I have also seen arguments like `lf`, so what is happening here, and how does it synergies with that serialEvent() function?

Thanks for the help, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bufferUntil(lf)` you set up your serial port to listen (write data to its buffer) until it gets a certain character (lf, which in the example you linked is the line feed character).

As you've noticed `bufferUntil(lf)` won't actually read any data. To read the data the port received you need to define an interrupt function where you call `readString`:

```
void serialEvent(Serial port)
   { inString = port.readString(); }
```

This function will be called (interrupting the normal flow of your program and hence its name) automatically as soon as the serial port receives the character you defined with `bufferUntil(lf)`; that'll be until the line feed character for the example. After reading data from the port's buffer your program will return to wherever it was interrupted.

**EDIT:** What is a buffer? The buffer is either a software (a variable hidden in the library that you're using) or hardware (a bank of memory on the serial port chip) place where you store data coming to the port (this one is the reception buffer, but there is also a transmission buffer for the info you send out through the port).

Think of it as a bucket for bits or bytes. In an analogy with water flow coming out of the tap, you can open your tap and place a glass under it if you want to have a glass of water. But it might be that you want to drink your water later, so you can place a bucket (water buffer) to store water for you. In this case, the `bufferUntil(lf)` statement would be the action of placing the bucket and you can think of the `serialEvent` as the action of taking water from the bucket (the fact that you are using the bucket allows you to keep doing your errands around the house but at some point the bucket will overflow unless you either close the tap or start emptying it, and to do that you have to interrupt your normal flow of activities).

Why do we need buffers? Well, you could be polling (listening on the port from the main task of your software) continuously but then your code would be very inefficient. With buffers you're allowed  to do other things (calculating stuff, reading data from sensors or whatever) and you'll only check the port when you're sure (because your routine was interrupted) when the data you want is there. In this case, the data you want is indicated with the character you used as an argument in the `bufferUntil(lf)` function.

I hope I did not overstretch the analogies.

Comment: Sorry, this is probably a bad question, but what is the buffer?

Comment: No worries, there is no such thing as a bad question. I have updated my answer with a new paragraph. I hope it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: Alright! Now I’m getting it, just 2 more questions? 1) Do you need the bufferUntil() line, what happens if you don’t have it and data is sent to the buffer (I can say this sentence now because I understand it from you :) )? 2) Do you only need this if you are reading from the port, like this wouldn’t be needed if you were just sending to the port, right? 3(bonus) ) Does serialEvent detect when something had been written to the buffer, more clearly, it just reads the buffer that took data from the Serial port?

Comment: 1) The way you're working in this example you need to have the `bufferUntil`, otherwise you'll keep storing data in the buffer but nothing will happen (eventually, like the bucket, the buffer will overflow and you'll be losing data). With the library you're using you can also read a fixed number of bytes instead of until, if you work this way you don't need the ´bufferUntil`. 2) For writing you might have buffers as well but you won't see the `bufferUntil` (it makes no sense to work that way becasue you know exactly what you're sending)

Comment: Okay, so would serialEvent not work without bufferUntil? Bye the way thanks so much for taking your time to help me when you could be doing so many other things!

Comment: 3) you can understand serialEvent` as an employee that you contract to keep an eye on your bucket while it's filling. So, yes, there will be some part of your code that is checking the port looking for the stop character but the same way you don't need to use your own resoruces if you contract somebody to do the job, the port can be more efficient polling itself (because it does it with using its own hardware resources).

Comment: would serialEvent not work without bufferUntil? No, you need to have either `bufferUntil` or read a fixed number of bytes (for that you need to set it up with [`buffer`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_buffer_.html)

Comment: No problem, enjoy your coding.

Comment: :) haha okay, you too!